# Generating pdf, getting text from ckeditor in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ckeditor, rails-admin

I've created a form with several fields, and many of them use ckeditor, I know that separately I can generate a pdf of each field, but I have normal fields (string, date), and I wanted them to be in pdf. I tried with the prawn but it does not render the ckeditor html tags. How to generate a pdf with these fields, those of the ckeditor rendering the html tags, and the others appearing normally?

Comment: Have you looked into `wkhtmltopdf`? Turns css/html into pdf. Make sure to include styles for ckeditor

Comment: Got it, I've been seeing about it, but how do I use it with rails_admin? I did not find any documentation.

Comment: You'll probably need to manually hack / monkey patch it to work together

Comment: You have to retrieve the forms values (params) then using them in another view and make this view look like what you want your PDF to look like (you can use CSS). Then use `wkhtmltopdf` to convert this view to a PDF, this is fairly easy. Regarding the HTML tags <div> <ul> <li> you won't see it in your view when you paste the value inside your view. You can also `sanitize` your value so that you have only certain tags, and not all.

Comment: I built the template as the PDF will be, but I have not yet been able to generate a pdf. He, or nothing happens, or gives error, an error that says nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to process the following html tags present in the ckeditor for prawn to understand:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@string)
```